# Show popup after ending the call in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need to show Popup Dialog after the ending call like true caller for save the contact number in the database, So is it possible in flutter for android? My Code have in kotlin Language. So if you have any Solution, Please Let me know.

I am a fresher in the development field, so if you have any suggestions please let me know.

Thank you.

.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder due to deal with Flutter async Programming.

futurebuilder is using the place that single api call ex) POST of Restful Api. Or they have one and only one response

Streambuilder can be assimilated to a value that can change over time but same usage in Futurebuilder

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: _future(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData == false) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  
                  child: Text(
                    'Error: ${snapshot.error}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                );
              }

              else {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),

                  child: Text(
                    snapshot.data.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                );
              }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this ,

```
   SizedBox(
          height: 30,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _showCallDetail(context);
            },
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              foregroundColor: Colors.cyan,
            ),
            child: const Icon(Icons.call_end, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
```

Alert function

```
  Future<void> _showCallDetail(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, 
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Center(child: Text('Call Ended')),
          content: const SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(child: Text("Call log id : 563834948")),
                Center(child: Text('Duration: 32:42 ')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('close'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

there is a package named,[share plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus/example) try that one